# Read in a csv file using wildcards

Tags: python, pandas, wildcard

I need to read in a csv file daily but certain numbers in the file name will change each day. The filename with directory included  is `C:\siglocal\pairoffs\\logs_20220804_084056_9500_capped_delta_for_singlestockdelta.csv`

I have tried the below where I enter an asterisk after the _08 on the first row of the file path here. There are 9 digits after this part of the file name that change daily and then the last part of the file name (_capped_delta_for_singlestockdelta.csv) stays the same.

Any ideas what I need to do here?

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\siglocal\pairoffs\\logs_20220804_08*' + '_capped_delta_for_singlestockdelta.csv')
```

Comment: You can list files in the directory and select the right/latest one

Comment: Take a look at the *glob* module. Use that to identify the files

Comment: sorry a bit more info on either response would be much appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see how this is a pandas problem. If I understand correctly you are looking for a possibility to build a string with variables. Here you can use the `.format()` statements:

```
r'C:\siglocal\pairoffs\\logs_20220804_08{0}_capped_delta_for_singlestockdelta.csv'.format(day)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use os.walk(...) and a regular expression to evaluate the files in the folder.  Here's one possible implementation:

```
import os
import re


# define the folder where the files are located
src_folder = r"C:\_temp"

# define the regular expression to filter the files
file_regex = "logs_20220804_08([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[09][0-9][0-9][0-9])" \
             + "_capped_delta_for_singlestockdelta.csv"

for dir_path, dir_names, file_names in os.walk(src_folder):
    # Each iteration contains:
    # dir_path - current folder for the iteration
    # dir_names - list of folders in the dir_path.
    # file_names - list of files in the dir_path.
    for file_name in file_names:
        print("Evaluating file({}) in folder({})"
              .format(file_name, dir_path))
        match_obj = re.match(file_regex, file_name, re.M | re.I)
    
        # match_obj will be None if there isn't a match
        if match_obj:
            print("{}File({}) matches our regular expression."
                  .format(" " * 5, file_name))
            print("{}Changing number value is: {}"
              .format(" " * 5, match_obj.group(1)))
        else:
            print("{}No match for file ({})"
                  .format(" " * 5, file_name))
```